# USA L2 EAD processing

Tags: working-visas

Some questions about LS EAD processing:

1. How long is the processing time?
2. Filed mid-September still no response.
3. What are the formal ways of finding out on the status of the EAD application?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>According to this [USCIS page](https://my.uscis.gov/helpcenter/article/how-long-does-uscis-have-to-make-a-decision-on-my-form-i-765-application-for-employment-authorization), they have 90 days to make a decision, but if they require extra documentation from you then the 90-day clock resets back to zero when they receive that documentation from you.</strike>

As noted by user102008, USCIS has abandoned the 90-day processing timeframe.
Instead, you can check on current processing time at the [USCIS Processing Time Information](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do) page.
You'll need to know which office or service center your application was submitted to.

You can also check on the status of your application through [this USCIS page](https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do).

Comment: The regulations for 90-day EAD processing timeframe were removed in January 2017. Maybe that page is outdated.

Comment: @user102008 - any idea where I'd find some reference to the new regs?

Comment: It's part of a huge set of changes (https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2016/11/18/2016-27540/retention-of-eb-1-eb-2-and-eb-3-immigrant-workers-and-program-improvements-affecting-high-skilled); you can find it buried in there somewhere